# I got an error while installing Ubuntu using windows installer

Tags: system-installation, error-handling, helpfile

I got this error, please help:

```
An error has occurred setting the element data.
The request is not supported.
```

Comment: Is your disk dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

Open disk management in Windows and check to see if the partition type for Windows is set to dynamic, if it is than you need to change it to basic but that requires you to delete your partitions if I remember correctly.

If you're planning on fully switching over to Linux what you can do is put it onto a DVD or USB and install it from there, it should give you the option to uninstall Windows. What is good about this is that it'll make Ubuntu run faster than installing it from inside Windows.

If you're just planning on trying it out to see if you like it you can always just preview it and not actually install it (again, from a DVD/USB stick). I hope this has helped you a bit. -Coldy